# eslint-plugin-prettier not recognized globally by VS Code

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have the package `eslint-plugin-prettier` installed globally.

`npm list --depth=0 -g` results:

```
/usr/local/lib
├── babel-eslint@10.0.1
├── eslint@5.12.1
├── eslint-config-react-redux@1.0.6
├── eslint-plugin-prettier@3.0.1
├── npm@6.5.0
└── prettier@1.16.1
```

But, in my projetc, the eslint file is not loaded, and returns me the follow error:

`[Error - 12:42:27 AM] Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier' Referenced from: /my/workspace/directory/.eslintrc.json Referenced from: my/workspace/directory/my/project/directory/package.json`

Solutions?